# Cannot Open Matching Workbooks After Dropdown Selection

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

**INITIAL QUESTION**

Why am I not able to open all (all three) matching workbooks?

Dropdown selection:

**1A:1C = Company1 Company2 Company3**

**2A:2C = Version2 Version1 Version1**

Only the first one (Company1, Version2) will open...

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()

Dim ColumnIndex1 As Integer
Dim ColumnIndex2 As Integer
Dim ColumnIndex3 As Integer
Dim ColumnIndex4 As Integer
Dim ColumnIndex5 As Integer
Dim ColumnIndex6 As Integer

For ColumnIndex1 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex1).Value = "Company1" And Cells(2,      
ColumnIndex1).Value = "Version1" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company1\Version1.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex1

For ColumnIndex2 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex2).Value = "Company1" And Cells(2,
ColumnIndex2).Value = "Version2" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company1\Version2.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex2

For ColumnIndex3 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex3).Value = "Company2" And Cells(2,
ColumnIndex3).Value = "Version1" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company2\Version1.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex3

For ColumnIndex4 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex4).Value = "Company2" And Cells(2, 
ColumnIndex4).Value = "Version2" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company2\Version2.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex4

For ColumnIndex5 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex5).Value = "Company3" And Cells(2, 
ColumnIndex5).Value = "Version1" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company3\Version1.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex5

For ColumnIndex6 = 1 To 3
If Cells(1, ColumnIndex6).Value = "Company3" And Cells(2, 
ColumnIndex6).Value = "Version2" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\Company3\Version2.xlsx"
End If
Next ColumnIndex6

End Sub
```

I have just started using VBA (and StackOverflow).

Thank you.

**FOLLOW-UP**

@ Dirk Reichel:
@ All:

I have tried to expand Dirk's idea a bit (See below), and I'm trying to open 5 (or less) workbooks in sequence each time copying/pasting a specific range to the 'main2' sheet of the 'main' workbook.

It works fine unless I open fewer workbooks than the number of dropdown values that are being checked (I'm currently using 5 dropdown sets instead of the original 3: see top of page):

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim MainWorkbook As Workbook
Dim DataWorkbook As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Set MainWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

With MainWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To 6

If ActiveSheet.Cells(6, i).Value <> "" Then

Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("D:\ 'some folders' \" & .Cells(6, 
i).Value & "-" & .Cells(10, 2) & "-" & .Cells(7, i).Value & ".xlsx")
DataWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:Q3").Copy
MainWorkbook.Sheets("Main2").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial

On Error Resume Next

End If

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

I have used 3 of the (now) 5 dropdown menus, and only 1 workbook is currently being opened and copied...

Comment: Simply change the `If ActiveSheet.Cells(6, i).V.....` to `If .Cells(6, i).V.....`... that should do the trick ;)

Comment: @ Dirk Reichel:
I will give it a try...
Thank again. 
Cheers!

Comment: @ Dirk Reichel:
@ All:

I have posted a 'follow-up' in my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102818/copy-paste-data-from-multiple-data-workbooks-to-a-single-main-workbook-based.

Answer (score 3):

You may try an easier script like this:

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()
  Dim i As Long
  With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To 3
      Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\" & .Cells(1, i).Value & "\" & .Cells(2, i).Value & ".xlsx"
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

if your `Cells` do not have any "Workbook" and "Worksheet" they will do it with the active one (after opening the first workbook, all your `Cells` will refer to it and not to the orginal source)

Comment: What a beautiful answer @Dirk Reichel. This is a great example of looking for commonalities in code and using them to get rid of the excess, leaving it perfectly DRY.

Comment: @ Dirk Reichel:
Very efficient and concise! Thank you!
Herzliche Grüße (No, I'm not German). :-)